# Hopper disassembler ASM

Tags: reverse-engineering, jailbreak, tweak, hopper

I am using the Hopper Disassembler to reverse engineer an iOS library. In principle, in the beginning, everything is clear and logical. But I can't find information about asm. What does asm mean? Is this a function call? If this is a function, what does it do? Thanks!

[Disassembled code screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9mzYx.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's inline assembly, equivalent to the `asm` keyword in C. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inline_assembler) might serve as an introduction.
You almost certainly get this because Hopper fails to properly decompile the instruction. In your case it's arm64 assembly (formally the A64 instruction set) as outlined in the [ARMv8 Reference Manual](https://developer.arm.com/docs/ddi0487/latest).

Also, `xN` or `wN` in assembly should correspond to `rN` in the decompiled code, so you should be able to make *some* sense of the output you get.